# Spring security Taglib

Tags: spring, security, exception, spring-security, taglib

i want use spring security taglibs in my jsf project,so I've made ​​the following changes to the project,but I get this Exception:

> Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler. Please
>   see server.log for more details.

What am I doing wrong here?
i use :

> netbeans 7.1.2 --spring mvc 3.0.6-- spring security 3.1.1--glassfish 3.1.2 and jsf 2.1

**springsecurity.taglib.xml:**

```
   <!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
  "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
  "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
    <namespace>http://www.springframework.org/security/tags</namespace>
    <tag>
        <tag-name>authorize</tag-name>
        <handler-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagHandler</handler-class>
    </tag>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAllGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAllGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areAnyGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areAnyGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>areNotGranted</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean areNotGranted(java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
    <function>
        <function-name>isAllowed</function-name>
        <function-class>org.springframework.faces.security.FaceletsAuthorizeTagUtils</function-class>
        <function-signature>boolean isAllowed(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<!--  /========================jsf config=============================/-->

  <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>#{sessionManager.theme}</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
     <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

  <!--  /========================spring config=============================/-->  

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/springsecurity.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
      org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher
    </listener-class>
  </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**mypage.xhtml:**

```
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
.
.
.
<sec:authorize access="ROLE_SUPERADMIN">
      <h:outputText value="test" />                          
</sec:authorize>
```

**mylib :**

```
    org.springframework.cglib-2.2   3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.aop 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.asm 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.aspects 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.beans   3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.context 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.context.support 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.core    3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.expression  3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.instrument 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.expression  3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.jdbc    3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.jms 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.orm 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.oxm 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.test    3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.tx  3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.web 3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.webmvc-portlet  3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.webmvc  3.0.6.RELEASE
    org.springframework.struts  3.0.6.RELEASE
    commons-logging-1.1.1
    jsf 2.1-jsf-api
    jsf 2.1 -jsf-impl
    jstl 1.1-standard
    jstl 1.1-jstl
    spring-security-ldap-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-config-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-core-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-taglibs-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-web-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will need to include [spring-faces](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/springframework/webflow/spring-faces/2.3.1.RELEASE/spring-faces-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar) in order to integrate spring security tags with faces. if you are using maven then would suggest to add [dependency](http://search.maven.org/#browse%7C1516720195) as this might will have jar dependency.

Comment: thanks for reply, but I've already done it and I get this Exception:org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/webflow/execution/RequestContext.

Comment: now you are missing webflow jars as mentioned above spring faces will depend on on other jars.

Comment: may be you can use www.jarfinder.com to findout about missing class/jar like http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/org.springframework.webflow.execution.RequestContext

Comment: yes,thanks add org.springframework.webflow-2.0.3.jar and org.springframework.binding-2.0.3.jar but again exception!!:  Unable to create a new instance of 'org.springframework.faces.webflow.FlowActionListener': java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Comment: thanks for your help,download org.springframework.webflow-2.3.1 and dependency from http://www.springsource.org/download/community?project=Spring%2520Web%2520Flow and add to lib ,resolve exception